# Does the E-Kaia device harvest electrical power from small plants?

Tags: consumer-products, plants

The E-Kaia device claims to be able to harvest electricity released into soil by small plants. [Here's a Daily Mail article describing it](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3078365/The-ultimate-power-plant-Biocircuit-harnesses-electricity-soil-houseplant-charge-mobile-phone.html).

> And because not all of the electrons are needed, harvesting them doesn't impact the plant.
>
> According to E-Kaia, the technology can output up to five volts at around 600 milliamps, and this can charge a phone in around an hour and a half.

Is this possible - does it actually charge in an hour and a half, and can electricity actually be produced from a pot plant?

Comment: (Clarification: USB B; USB C does support more than 500mA)

Comment: @JanDvorak I believe it is 3.3, although USB is 5V. A USB port is 0.5 by standard I believe. You can get more from a wall usb socket tho.

Comment: [this rather small battery](http://www.amazon.com/LG-EAC61638202-Battery-Cosmos-Non-Retail/dp/B00DTRHDTM/ref=sr_1_1?s=wireless&ie=UTF8&qid=1445780193&sr=1-1&refinements=p_n_feature_keywords_three_browse-bin%3A9244157011) has 900 mAh at 3.7V (making 1.5h * 5V * 600mA plausible) but [this battery](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BW0X892/ref=s9_top_hd_bw_g107_i1?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_r=1K9DJ9014ZSMYGWS91K6&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=2125197522&pf_rd_i=7073959011) has 2600 mAh and there much bigger batteries in the same category as well.

Comment: The more I look at this, it's starting to look less like a scam and more like an emerging piece of technology that the media just did a really poor job of explaining (which is way too common, unfortunately)

Comment: I assume you mean [potted plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potted_plant), not [pot plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marijuana).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard that's correct :) I'm from Australia and 'pot plant' has the same meaning as potted plant (AFAIK).

Comment: Can we delegate this to physics or biology.se where someone authoritative can explain why this is nonsense?

Comment: @shadur the explanation is nonsense, but it could still be based on technology based on a reasonable idea.

Comment: My fear is that this is little more than using soil as a medium for a battery. Ever made a potato battery?  It's not the potato that gives the energy.  The potato is only a buffer.   See also: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery

Comment: Oops, I see the linked Daily Mail page briefly describes such a soil-based battery: the Daniel cell.

Comment: I can't write a proper answer at the level skeptics require, but here is a source: E-kaya was a semifinalist at 2014's Harvard International Business Model Competition. [ref](http://www.businessmodelcompetition.com/past-winners.html).

Comment: I suspect they are simply utilizing the soil redox potential.

Comment: Well, it's 2019 and there's no information about the status of the tech. .3A at 5V seems highly unrealistic for a potted plant. There's no description of the mechanism to be found. I believe that the ratings reported by media were exaggerated, and I think other's are right in saying this is just a potato battery.